# Typescript with react-redux mapStateToProps called but component did not rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

lots of topics on this one but they are almost all about the state being mutated somehow, which is not my case I believe. So I have a state that is shared between two component.

```
export interface ImageStoreState {
    readonly name : string;
}
```

The reducer,

```
export function imageActionReducer(state: ImageStoreState, action:ImageActions): ImageStoreState {
  // Set up initial states
  if (state === undefined)
  {
    state = {
      name: ""
    }
  }

  console.log("original state", state);
  switch (action.type) {
      case getType(imageActions.saveImageMeta):
        console.log("SaveImageMeta Reducer.");
        return { ...state, 
          name: action.payload.name 
        };
    }

  console.error("No matching reducer.");
  return state;
}
```

The container,

```
export function mapStateToProps(state: ImageStoreState) : IAddImageControlProps {
  const { name } = state;
  console.log("Add image control container, mapStateToProps", state);
  return {
      imageChosen: name
  }
}

export function mapDispatchToProps() {
  return {
      // 
  };
}

export const AddImageControlContainer 
  = connect<IAddImageControlProps, {}, IAddImageControlProps, ImageStoreState>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddImageControl);
```

The presentation component,

```
export interface IAddImageControlProps {
  imageChosen?: string;
  // onImageAdded?: (im: ImageFile) => any;
}

export class AddImageControl extends React.Component<IAddImageControlProps, {}> {
  constructor(props : IAddImageControlProps) {
      super(props);
  }

  public componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: IAddImageControlProps) {
    console.log('componentWillReceiveProps', nextProps);
  }

  public render() : JSX.Element {
    const { imageChosen } = this.props;

    let isEnabled = false;
    if (imageChosen !== undefined)
    {
      isEnabled = true;
      console.log(imageChosen);
    }
    console.log("Should enbale:" + isEnabled);

    return (
      <section>
        <Button type="button" color="success" disabled={!isEnabled}>Add it!</Button>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

I am using redux dev-tools so I can see the states are changing,
[image]

But the lines

```
console.log('componentWillReceiveProps', nextProps);

console.log("Should enbale:" + isEnabled);
```

Never get called!

Thank you in advance, everyone! I have been wondering this for a few days already.

Comment: Looks like your state has a top-level `images` key, so you'll need to destructure it  like this `const {images: { name }} = state;` in `mapStateToProps`.

Comment: @Oblosys Thanks but that key is coming from the combine reducer `export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    images: imageActionReducer
}); `
I am not sure how to destructure it in mapStateToProps...

Comment: You can use the code fragment from my comment :-)

Comment: @Oblosys OMG you are such a lifesaver! The problem is, I typed the state as ImageStoreState which does not include the top level `images`. Huge thanks :))